# Фильтрация kendo data grid row с помощью выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo

Здравствуйте, я пытаюсь сделать фильтр колонки SystemMessage с помощью выпадающего списка, но у меня генерируются checkboxs. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку.

```
   <script>
var yesNoDropDownDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [{ value: "true", text: "Yes" }, { value: "false", text: "No" }]
});

function yesNoFilter(element) {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
         dataSource: 
            yesNoDropDownDataSource,                   
        optionLabel: "--Select Value--"
    });
}

</script>
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CommentsViewModel>()
    .Name("GridComment")
     .Columns(columns =>
     {
         columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title(@Resources.General.DetailsSearch_COMM_Name).ClientTemplate("<div><a href=''>#=Name#</a></div><div>#=Template#</div>").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(250);
         columns.Bound(p => p.Comment).Title(Resources.General.DetailsSearch_COMM_Comment).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(150);
         columns.Bound(p => p.Action).Title(@Resources.General.DetailsSearch_COMM_Action).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(150);
         columns.Bound(p => p.SystemMessage).Title(@Resources.General.DetailsSearch_COMM_SystemMsg).ClientTemplate("#=SystemMessage ?"+"'"+@Resources.General.Yes+"'"+" : "+"'"+@Resources.General.No+"'"+" #")
             .Filterable(filterable =>
             {
                 filterable.Extra(false);

             filterable.UI("yesNoFilter");
             })


                                     .Width(150);
         columns.Bound(p => p.Company).Title(@Resources.General.DetailsSearch_COMM_CompanyName).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(150);
         columns.Bound(p => p.ReleaseID).Title(@Resources.General.DetailsSearch_COMM_ReleaseID).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(150);
         columns.Bound(p => p.User).Title(@Resources.General.DetailsSearch_COMM_CreatedBy).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(150);
         columns.Bound(p => p.DateAndTime).Title(@Resources.General.DetailsSearch_COMM_CreatedDate).Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm tt}").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false))).Width(150);

     })

     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Model(model =>
     {
         model.Id(x => x.SpecificationId);
         model.Field(x => x.Name).Editable(false);
         model.Field(x => x.Comment).Editable(false);
         model.Field(x => x.Action).Editable(false);
         model.Field(x => x.SystemMessage).Editable(false);
         model.Field(x => x.Company).Editable(false);
         model.Field(x => x.ReleaseID).Editable(false);
         model.Field(x => x.User).Editable(false);
         model.Field(x => x.DateAndTime).Editable(false);

     })
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetCommentsDetaliesGrid", "SpecificationListSuppliers").Data("filterdata"))
         )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(700))
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))

    )
```